# Assign more specific generic type to less specific type

Tags: c#, generics

I'd like to instantiate instances of a generic type and pass them around as if they were generic objects of an interface that they implement, such as below. Clearly, this is not allowed. Why is this, and what is the general practice for handling such situations? thanks.

```
public class MyType<T> where T : IComparable { }
```

```
MyType<IComparable> things = new MyType<Int32>();
```

this gets error:
`Cannot implicitly convert type MyType<Int32> to MyType<IComparable>`

I want to do this because I need different types of `things` that I want to pass around to more generic methods such as

```
public void DoSomething(MyType<IComparable> things) {...}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what the relationship is between Int32, IComparable, and MyType, although as a rule, concrete objects do not have generic variance whereas interfaces do.

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Comment: @DavidL MyType is generic on type T where T implements IComparable. Int32 implements IComparable. Sorry, should have included that.

Comment: You should be able to implement `DoSomething` as generic method `DoSomething<T>` the same way, you implement `MyType`. In this way you can pass a concrete instance of `MyType<Int32>` to it and should be able to do whatever you want 

Comment: While Int32 "is-a" IComparable, MyType<Int32> is not a  MyType<IComparable>. They are completely unrelated. And they are not mutually assignable.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment compatibility of generic type arguments does not make the generic type itself assignment compatible. This is why: Let's assume that we declared the generic class like this:

```cs
public class MyType<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And let's assume that this would compile ...

```cs
var intObject = new MyType<int> { Value = 42 };
MyType<IComparable> things = intObject; // Does not compile!
```

... then we could write

```cs
// things.Value has the static type IComparable
things.Value = "hello"; // Allowed because string is IComparable
```

But this is not possible since the underlying object is a `MyType<int>` and thus its `Value` property has the type `int`. Therefore, we are not allowed to substitute a `MyType<int>` for a `MyType<IComparable>`.